# Why maven compiler plugin in child pom not inheriting configuration from compiler plug in parent pom

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

My parent pom defines maven compiler plugin as :

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
             <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

My child pom not inheriting the above plugin from parent pom, even I tried referencing the parent pom plugin as follows :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- inherits config from parent -->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Please help, how to refer parent pom compiler plugin in child pom.

Comment: How do you know the inheritance isn't working?

Comment: @Tunaki because I can see in cmd that it is using default plugin with java 1,5

Comment: Oh I did not notice the version of the plugin, it's quite old. Update to `3.6.0` instead of 2.3.2. And you don't need the `<inherited>true</inherited>`, remove that. After that, are you sure the parent was installed in the local repository? Is this is a multi-module Maven project?

Comment: Hi, as you said, removed the <inherited> tag and updated the version, still it is giving the same error. Do I need to do something in settings.xml file ??

Comment: No -- as you commented before, are you sure the parent was installed in the local repository? Is this is a multi-module Maven project?

Comment: yes it is a multi module maven project, i am trying to build the same project on different machine. First I did mvn clean install on parent pom. now while doing mvn clean install on project, I am getting error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129345/discussion-between-tunaki-and-dwingle).